# Use onClick in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with `content_scripts`. When page loads i'm appending new element to `DOM` using jquery:

```js
urlTarget.parent().prepend("<div class='scout status' onClick='test()' data-domain='" + domainKey + "'></div>");
```

This works fine. I also defined a function inside my `inject.js` content script:

```js
function test() {
    alert("this is test");
    return false;
}
```

After clicking appended element i get following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined`

I've been reading about security restrictions in chrome extension framework (see [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)), but i'm not sure if they are applied to content script also (documentation shows popup example), or am i am missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you append the new element to DOM and register event listeners via `onClick=XXX`, in fact the browser expects that `XXX` is from page script. However, you know [content scripts are isolated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), they can't directly access variables/functions created by the page, and vice versa.

So here comes two workarounds:

1. Add an `id` for the inserted element, and bind event listener in the content script via the following way

   ```js
   // Assuming the id is ID
   document.getElementById('ID').addEventListener('click', test);
   ```
2. Append a `script` tag into the page ([Use a content script to access the page context variables and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script))

   ```js
   var actualCode = `
     function test() {
       alert("this is test");
       return false;
     }
   `;

   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.textContent = actualCode;
   (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
   script.remove();
   ```

Comment: Thanks that explains script behavior. Actually my purpose is to dynamically call a function from inside of inject script. By dynamically i mean when handling click on appended element that contains data attribute value with name of the function to be called, i will be able to call this function "from string". Instead of `onClick` i have also tried `eval()` - but, effect is the same.